# Niagara Falls mist

Tags: thermodynamics

I am at Niagara Falls and noticed that the mist increased significantly at night and in the early morning.  I guess it is acting like a cooling tower.  Why is this happening?

Comment: This question could be better if, rather than asking for thoughts, you actually asked a physics question.

Comment: Though still in beta, you might try asking at http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/ if you're getting a chilly reception here.

Comment: For Niagra in particular it is worth noting that they divert a large fraction of the flow for power generation (which means that, yes, what you oohed and aahed about is only a patch on the natural state of the falls!), and that they take much more at night than during the days (because they want to continue to benefit from the tourist value of the site).

Answer (score 1):

Warm air supports greater humidity (absorbs more moisture) than cool air.  At night and in the early morning, when the air is cool, evaporation from river water at Niagara Falls hits cooler air which does not as readily absorb water, so is capable of less humidity, than warmer air during the day, so the river evaporation becomes visible as water vapor droplets hanging in the cool early morning and night air.

Ground water holds heat well into the night, whereas air cools off more quickly.  Therefore, water will continue to evaporate during the night and early morning.  Heat released during evaporation initially supports humidity over the water, but as the humid air rises and cools off, the evaporated water condenses as vapor.